# Is it possible to Backup a QnA Maker Knowledge with Azure Pipelines?

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-qna-maker

Im working with bots from the Microsoft Bot Framework (SDK4).

My Bot is connected with LUIS and two KnowledgeBases.

The CI/CD process is realized with Azure Pipelines.

Im wondering if it is possible to backup a knowledge Base with the Release Pipeline within Azure Pipelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to write a script in azure pipeline to download the knowledge base from QnA Maker programmatically.

The download process is programmatically available using the following [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/qnamaker/knowledgebase/download):

```
GET {Endpoint}/qnamaker/v4.0/knowledgebases/{kbId}/{environment}/qna
```

You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/migrate-knowledge-base#programmatically-migrate-a-knowledge-base-from-qna-maker) for details.